# Jest objectContaining method that uses toBe instead of toEqual property checks?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

Is there a method similar to `objectContaining` that uses `toBe` instead of `toEqual` property checks?

The following contrived test case (which passes) highlights the issue.  I would like to assert that the `button` property of the object passed to `foo` is actually `button1` and should therefore fail for the similar object `button2`.

```
test('foo', () => {
  const button1 = document.createElement('button');
  const button2 = document.createElement('button');
  const foo = jest.fn();
  foo({button: button1});
  expect(foo).toBeCalledWith(expect.objectContaining({button: button2}));
});
```

Alternatively, how could I rewrite this test case to support my required assertions?

Answer (score 0):

I think the way that the output is compared in your test will cause it to pass due to the argument actually being read as:

```
{ "button": <button /> }
```

Rather than an instance of a document element.

You could always assign a unique ID to each button during creation to make the assertion stick.

```
test('foo', () => {
    const button1 = document.createElement('button');
    const button2 = document.createElement('button');
    button1.id = 'button1';
    button2.id = 'button2';
    const foo = jest.fn();
    foo({button: button1});
    expect(foo).toBeCalledWith({button: button1}); // Will pass
    expect(foo).toBeCalledWith({button: button2}); // Will fail
});
```

If you want to use toBe()'s strict equality check, I'm not aware of a comparable Object Contains method with Jest, but you could interrogate the arguments that Jest provides:

```
expect(foo.mock.calls[0][0].button).toBe(button1);
```

Comment: Yes, adding an attribute will allow the `toEqual` property check to fail, but it's still not testing for identity which is what is required

Comment: You could use the array of args that Jest exposes on the `calls` response, allowing you to use toBe and get a strict equality check